# Negate the following statement

Tags: logic

> The integer $n$ is even if and only if $n^2 + 1$ is even.

The professor wrote that the negation of this statement is

> The integer $n$ is even if and only if $n^2 + 1$ is odd.

I am pretty sure this is wrong because I even drew the truth tables for this. Let the first statement be $P$ and the second be $Q$. Since
$P\Leftrightarrow Q $, we can write the negation as

$$\text{(P and not Q) OR (Q and not P)}$$

Can someone please confirm if the answer the professor wrote was true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is assumed to refer to a specific, unknown, given number, your professor is correct. But if the complete statement is implicitly universally quantified over n ("For all integer $n$, $n$ is even if and only if $n^2+1$ is even"), then your professor is wrong. You need this:

**There exists an integer $n$ such that if $n$ is even then $n^2+1$ is odd.**

Comment: Oh, I understand, thanks. The answer I gave at the end is not wrong is it?

Comment: @NavySeal: Your negation is correct, and so is the professor’s; they’re logically equivalent.

Comment: @NavySeal: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Changed my answer.

Comment: @Paiam: As phrased, the original statement is in fact about a specific integer: **the** integer $n$.